# Gracefully handle template rendering errors in gin-gonic

Tags: go, go-gin

I'm learning Go and using gin-gonic for a web application. I'm trying to recover gracefully from template errors and haven't been able to figure out how to buffer output or redirect properly to achieve this.

With this code:

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

func main() {
    g := gin.New()
    g.LoadHTMLGlob("templates/*")
    g.Use(func(c *gin.Context) {
        defer func() {
            if err := recover(); err != nil {
                c.HTML(http.StatusInternalServerError, "error.tmpl", nil)
            }
        }()

        c.Next()
    })
    g.GET("/", func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.HTML(http.StatusOK, "index.tmpl", gin.H{"var": 4})
    })
    g.Run(":80")
}
```

where templates/index.tmpl is

```
Before
<br>
Bad: {{.var.x}}
<br>
After
```

and templates/error.tmpl is

```
Oops! We encountered an error.
```

when I load my page, I see

```
Before
Bad: Oops! We encountered an error.
```

and the response code ends up being 200. I'd prefer to cleanly catch the error so that the only thing displayed to the user is

```
Oops! We encountered an error.
```

the response code comes out as 500, and the error gets logged on the server for later investigation.

What's the best way within gin to catch template errors without showing partial output to the user? I've seen several examples of accomplishing this with buffering using the built-in net/http stuff, but haven't been able to find anything for a good way to handle it in gin.

### Edited with solution

Building off of @big pigeon's comments on the accepted answer, I ended up executing the template myself into a buffer and using `c.Data()` to display it if there were no errors. This still seems less than ideal since it bypasses features like `multitemplate`'s ability to dynamically reload a parsed template at runtime in dev builds, but it works. The updated proof-of-concept code looks like:

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "html/template"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

func main() {
    g := gin.New()
    g.LoadHTMLGlob("templates/*")
    g.Use(func(c *gin.Context) {
        defer func() {
            if err := recover(); err != nil {
                c.HTML(http.StatusInternalServerError, "error.tmpl", nil)
            }
        }()

        c.Next()
    })
    g.GET("/", func(c *gin.Context) {
        if tmpl, err := template.ParseFiles("templates/index.tmpl"); err != nil {
            panic(err)
        } else {
            buf := &bytes.Buffer{}
            if err = tmpl.Execute(buf, gin.H{"var": 4}); err != nil {
                panic(err)
            } else {
                c.Data(http.StatusOK, "text/html; charset=utf-8", buf.Bytes())
            }
        }
    })
    g.Run(":80")
}
```

Using buffer pooling, pre-parsing templates, and other such niceties are left as an exercise to any future readers.

If anyone knows of a better way to handle this without bypassing gin's parsing/rendering features, I'm very open to it.

Comment: `Bad: {{.var.x}}` might have to read `{{.var}}`

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen indeed, that would fix the error. I included that intentionally to show what happens when there's a template error. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Idiomatic way to handle template errors in golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30821745/idiomatic-way-to-handle-template-errors-in-golang/30822458#30822458).

Comment: @icza unfortunately gin-gonic keeps that template execute call internal. I'm looking for a way to do it with gin specifically. Maybe the answer is that it's not possible.

Comment: AH, now I understand your question. Graceful error handling in go itself is pretty clear. The idiomatic way as linked by @icza is the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you must be sure the Template render correctly,Because c.HTML will write directly to response, at this time some byte has been sent to client.

you can use "html/template", and use buff to cache response data, instead of writing directly to response writer

Comment: Unfortunately gin-gonic keeps that template execute call internal. I'm looking for a way to do it with gin specifically. Maybe the answer is that it's not possible with gin without Executing the template twice.

Comment: @Parnic use context.Data method, it will write bytes data to response.Writer

Comment: The context.Data tip helped me out, thanks. I ended up executing the html template myself and writing the result to Data if there were no errors, otherwise displaying my error page via HTML().